# How to get my WorkbenchAdvisor in Eclipse RCP 3.x?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse API requires me to create an instance of `WorkbenchAdvisor` class and pass it to [`org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench()`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor.html).

Suppose I have used this instance to hold some application-wide data.

How to access this class instance from some view, for example?

I tried something like

```
ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor advisor = (ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.class);
```

but it fails.

Answer (score 2):

The workbench does not provide a way to get the `WorkbenchAdvisor`, there is even a comment in the Workbench code to say they do not want it accessed from plug-ins.

Update:
The subclass of `WorkbenchAdvisor` you provide can access plenty of other APIs to do things in the overridden methods. However it seems not to be intended that you store anything in the advisor for other classes. In 3.x RCPs data tends to be stored in plug-in Activator instance data or using OSGi services. In 4.x e4 RCPs things are better because you can put things in the Eclipse `context` which is available to all parts.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning. Namely advisor contains workbench-wide handlers like `preStartup()`. What these handlers can do, if advisor is totally internal?

Comment: Added some more to the answer on my understanding of the design (I am not an Eclipse designer).